# Testing Deno Jupyter Kernel in Google Colab

Tags: typescript, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, deno

I am running into Google Colab installation/configuration problems.

- *My objective: Execute Typescript directly in a deno-based jupyter notebook kernel.*
- *My question: Did I correctly install everything as expected, or is there another library which is necessary to allow for Javascript/Typescript to directly run within the notebook, once I change the runtime type?*

**To reproduce my steps:**

1. Navigate to Google Colab and open a new notebook: https://colab.google/ and run each of the following commands directly in individual notebook cells.
2. !pip install jupyterlab

```
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (4.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: async-lru>=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from jupyterlab) (2.0.4)
....
```

3. !curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sudo DENO_INSTALL=/usr/local sh

```
######################################################################## 100.0%
Archive:  /usr/local/bin/deno.zip
  inflating: /usr/local/bin/deno     
Deno was installed successfully to /usr/local/bin/deno
Run 'deno --help' to get started
```

4. !deno --version

```
deno 1.38.0 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 12.0.267.1
typescript 5.2.2
```

5. !jupyter kernelspec list

```
Available kernels:
  deno       /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/deno
  ir         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

6. !deno jupyter --unstable

```
ℹ️ Deno kernel is not yet installed, run `deno jupyter --unstable --install` to set it up
```

7. !deno jupyter --unstable --install

```
[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec deno in /root/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/deno
✅ Deno kernelspec installed successfully.
```

8. !deno run https://examples.deno.land/hello-world.ts

```
Download https://examples.deno.land/hello-world.ts
Hello, World!
```

9. If I run the following code in a cell it works, but

```
%%javascript
let x = 5;
let y = 2;
let z = x + y;
element.textContent = z
```

as expected javascript won't directly execute inside within a cell, unless I changes the runtime. Let's tackle that in the next step :)

```
let x = 5;
let y = 2;
let z = x + y;
console.log(z);
```

```
File "<ipython-input-2-43a8c54cf62a>", line 1
    let x = 5;
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

10. Runtime > Change runtime type > Deno

[image]

11. It just says: Connecting, but nothing happens, and then the following pop-up appears:

[image]

```
await connected: disconnected
Error: await connected: disconnected
    at https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/7ecc98b5a079533f6e1c231d23497bd7/external_polymer_binary.js:7118:372
```

I appreciate any help with this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did the guide your were following cover Google Colab or did it say it was for Jupyter? Just for context ... Google Colab is a highly modified version of Jupyter and so often directions & approaches described for modern Jupyter don't work. At this time, the Jupyter Google Colab is based on is a very old version and so a lot of the things for modern Jupyter don't work.

Comment: I tried getting the above to work in Colab in March 21 2024, still similar problems.